# How to use regex for literal numbers

Tags: bash, regex

I'm writing a script to curl a webpage and grep/sed/sort/tail for a number and then use nagios exit codes for monitoring. My bash script is as follows:

```
queue= curl -s 'site | grep -ohE 'READY":[0-9]+' |\
    sed 's/READY"://' | sort -n | tail -1

if [[ $queue =~ [0-1] ]]; then
    echo "OK - $queue current jobs."
    exit 0
fi

if [[ $queue =~ [2-3] ]]; then
    echo "WARNING - $queue current jobs in queue."
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $queue =~ [4-100] ]]; then
    echo "CRITICAL - $queue current jobs in queue."
    exit 2
fi
```

The issue that I'm running into is that it's returning any number beginning with 3 for example as warning. 3, 30, 300 etc, instead of just 3.

```
WARNING - 39 current jobs in queue.
```

Warning should only be 2-3 jobs where critical should be 4-100 jobs and ok 0-1.

How would I set the number range to only exit on the single digit and not multiple digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regexes. These are numbers and should be treated as such.

```
if [ $queue -lt 2 ]; then 
    echo "OK - $queue current jobs."
    exit 0
fi

if [ $queue -lt 4 ]; then 
    echo "Warning - $queue current jobs."
    exit 1
fi

if [ $queue -ge  4 ]; then
    echo "CRITICAL"
    exit 2
fi
```

`-lt` = less then; `-ge` = greater equal, see more [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: Specifically, regexes are text matches, and `[2-3]` matches the `3` in `39`.